# Why do I need to use a pointer to a pointer in this single function and not anywhere else?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

I am learning about pointers and one of my professor's assignments is to write a program where main does nothing but call the other functions. The program's functions do all the work and are in this order:

1. `main`: calls other functions; otherwise does almost nothing
2. `getSize`: asks the user how many strings they want
3. `getSpace`: gets an array in the heap of the size requested by user
4. `inputData`: allows the user to input strings and stores them in the array
5. `printData`: prints all the strings, one string per line
6. `destroy`: returns all space to the heap

All these functions (besides `main`) must return `void`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getSize(int *);
void getSpace(string **, int);
void inputData(string *, int);
void printData(string *, int);
void destroy(string *);

int main()
{
    int SIZE;
    string *ptrToArray;

    getSize(&SIZE);
    cout << endl;
    getSpace(&ptrToArray, SIZE);
    inputData(ptrToArray, SIZE);
    cout << endl;
    printData(ptrToArray, SIZE);
    destroy(ptrToArray);

    return 0;
}
```

I figured out that I had to use the address of my pointer that was going to hold the array in order to actually initialize and keep the value. What I don't get is why `getSpace` is the only place where I had to use a pointer to a pointer. As you can see in my prototypes, `getSpace` is the only function that accepts a pointer to a pointer.

```
void getSpace(string **ptrToptrToArray, int size)
{
    *ptrToptrToArray = new string[size];
}
```

Again, this code works, but I'm not sure why `getSpace` seems to be the only **required** place where I need a pointer to a pointer in order to change the array I'm pointing to, especially since `inputData` also changes the elements in the array.

Edit: Fixed return types from `void *` to `void`.

Comment: Hint: you don't really need to use pointers *anywhere*. It is your choice to use them.

Comment: your functions don't return ```void```, they return ```void *```.  I'm very much assuming you want them to return ```void```.

Comment: You need to mentally distinguish between *the pointer* and *the thing being pointed to*.   To change the pointer you need to know its address. To change the things being pointed to, you need to know *their* address - which you find out from the pointer.

Comment: Could also use a reference to a pointer.. `void getSpace(string *&ptr, int size) {ptr = new string[size];}`

Comment: You can replace whole `getSpace` function with `vector<string> mystrings(size);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the pointers are passed by value.
Assume ptrToArray is a pointer variable that sits in E8 and points to some garbage location D8.
If you didn't pass it by it's address than what you would get in the get function is another variable ptrToptrToArray that sits in F8 and points to garbage D8 and when you change it's value the real pointer wouldn't change.
What you do now is store your pointer's address in the ptrToptrToArray and then change the value of the pointer that your pointer points to. (I like this sentence ;) )

Comment: Although confusing, I get what you're trying to say. Are pointers basically passed by value then? I'm guessing yes because that would make so much more sense. Also, using your advice, wouldn't that mean that I would need to use a pointer to a pointer for my `destroy` function to change the real pointer's entire value by `delete`'ing it and setting it to 0?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you confirmed pointers are passed by value in the beginning of your answer. Please disregard my first question in the preceding comment.

Comment: In order to free the memory the pointer points to all you need is the address of the memory you want to free and that can be passed by value. once you free that memory the pointer will point to freed memory and you can't use it anymore. If you want to nullify the pointer as well then you are right and you will have to pass a pointer to that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

- ...where I need a pointer to a pointer in order to change the array I'm pointing to...

Wrong. `getSpace` doesn't change array, it changes the pointer. That's the diference.